# Is there a way to iterate through an excel column to check that every values' preceding value is higher by 1? E.g (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I am using the numpy and pandas modules to work with data from an excel sheet. I want to iterate through a column and make sure each rows' value is higher than the previous ones' by 1.

For example, cell A1 of excel sheet has a value of 1, I would like to make sure cell A2 has a value of 2. And I would like to do this for the entire column of my excel sheet.

The problem is I'm not sure if this is a good way to go about doing this.

This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

i = 1

df = pd.read_excel("HR-Employee-Attrition(1).xlsx")
out = df['EmployeeNumber'].to_numpy().tolist()
print(out)
for i in out:
 if out[i] + 1 == out[i+1]:
   if out[i] == 1470:
     break
   i += 1
   pass
 else:
   print(out[i])
   break
```

It gives me the error:
`IndexError: list index out of range`.

Could someone advise me on how to check every row in my excel column?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, you may need to iterate over the length of the list -1 to avoid the out of range:

```
for i in range(len(out)-1):
 if out[i] + 1 == out[i+1]:
   if out[i] == 1470:
     break
   i += 1
   pass
 else:
   print(out[i])
   break
```

but there is an easier way to achieve this though, which is:

```
df['EmployeeNumber'].diff()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using a for-loop for such a thing:

I've created an Excel-sheet, with two columns, like this:

```
Index   Name
    1      A
    2      B
           C
           D
           E
```

I selected the two numbers (1 and 2) and double-clicked on the right-bottom corner of the selection rectangle, while recording what I was doing, and this macro got recorded:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A6")
```

As you see, Excel does not write a for-loop for this (the for-loop might prove being a performance whole in case of large Excel sheets).

The result on my Excel sheet was:

```
Index   Name
    1      A
    2      B
    3      C
    4      D
    5      E
```